# Github Codespaces set up test MySQL server

Tags: mysql, docker, vscode-devcontainer, codespaces, github-codespaces

I have a MySQL server in production and at the moment for testing as well. I have a Dockerfile that installs dependencies in my codespace. How could I add a MySQL server that spins up with the devcontainer?

Comment: I apologise if this is the wrong site to ask the question.